# How to load a txt/.pgn.camera file and store it in matrices in c++/opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I want to load some camera files in order to calculate the fundamental matrix of two images. The files are in `.png.camera` format, `space-delimited`, from a free dataset. They look like:

```
2759.48 0 1520.69 
0 2764.16 1006.81 
0 0 1 
0 0 0
0.582226 -0.0983866 -0.807052 
-0.813027 -0.0706383 -0.577925 
-0.000148752 0.992638 -0.121118 
-8.31326 -6.3181 0.16107
```

The first 3 lines are the camera matrix K, so I want to store them in a matrix cv::Mat called K.

Lines 5-7 are the rotation matrix and last line is the translation vector.

I want to use these matrices to do some further calculations.

I wonder if I can do it through OpenCV (I use version 2.4.5).

Any suggestion would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is some existing opencv api but you can easily do it yourself :

```
float K[3];
float Rot1[9];
float Rot2[9];
float T[3];

FILE* f = fopen(".png.camera", "r");

if (f) {
  printf("File successfully opened.\n");

  fscanf(f, "%f %f %f", &K[0], &K[1], &K[2]);
  fscanf(f, "%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f", &Rot1[0], &Rot1[1], &Rot1[2], &Rot1[3], &Rot1[4], &Rot1[5], &Rot1[6], &Rot1[7], &Rot1[8]);
  fscanf(f, "%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f", &Rot2[0], &Rot2[1], &Rot2[2], &Rot2[3], &Rot2[4], &Rot2[5], &Rot2[6], &Rot2[7], &Rot2[8]);
  fscanf(f, "%f %f %f", &T[0], &T[1], &T[2]);

  fclose(f);
}
else
{
  printf("Cannot open file.\n");
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. But I want the values to be stored in OpenCV Matrices, e.g. Mat K(3,3, CV_32FC1). Could that be possible?

Comment: Use `&K.at(0,0)` instead of `&K[0]` (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#mat)

Comment: I used &K.at<float>(0,0) and now they can be stored into OpenCV matrices, but when I print them out, they seem to be filled with the same value -4.31602*10^8, that is not something from the text file.

Comment: How do you print them out ?

Comment: Just with cout<<"K="<<K.

Comment: Print the matrix before you read the file and after. Is it the same ?

Comment: Yes, it is the same, filled with this strange value. If I initialise it with zeros zeros(3,3, CV_32FC1); it is filled with zeros before and after. I guess it cannot store the values in the matrices??

Comment: I suppose `fopen` fails, try to pass the absolute path : `/home/or/whatever/.png.camera`

Comment: Nothing changes. Could it be that I should set it as an argument in the properties of Visual Studio?

Comment: No. I've edited my code, just add `printf` to be sure that the file is correctly opened.

Comment: Ok. You have to give the absolute path `fopen("C:\\YourDir\\.png.camera", "r")` or move your executable in the directory of `.png.camera`. If that doesn't work, you probably don't have the rights to read the file.

Comment: I have given the absolute path. Something is going wrong. Maybe I have to use another approach with getline() or something like this.

Comment: Yes, finally it worked. I had a problem with the file location. Thanks!